# C++. 2d vectors growing too big

Tags: c++, memory, vector, 2d-vector

I got 2 dimensional vectors that keep increase the size ( as it hold all the permutation pattern)  but when i forming 11 variables permutation my program will crash as the vectors are growing too big and my ram cant sustain it, how should i solve it ? i tried to output the formation as text but it taking too long n the text file growing too big as few GB and keep growing.

my laptop , i7 4700MQ , 8GB ram , Windows 8.1 Pro x64

below is the code I use to form the 2d Vectors.

```
while (next_permutation(route.begin() + 1, route.end())) { 
        //check for every route permutation
        //first store route pattern x inside 1st vector,then will store the next route pattern in another row.
            for (counter = 0; counter < route.size(); counter++) {
                routePattern.push_back(route[counter]);
            }
            routeFormation.push_back(routePattern);
            routePattern.clear();

        }
```

Comment: In the usual trade-off between speed and space (you can seldom have both at the same type), you can continue to use vectors and keep things in memory, but then you can't keep as much data as you apparently want; Or you can save all data to disk, and can then have lots of data, but it will be slower to process.

Comment: what is the best method to contain the data to disk ? seem like text file is not a good idea right

Comment: If you [memory map the file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can treat it as normal memory, and store data in the native binary format. You can keep a normal vector to keep track of the size of each "row", which makes it easier to find a specific row in the memory mapped file.

Comment: You can use thread where one thread writes to the file while the other thread computes the permutation, this way you'll be using up the time efficiently while you will ensure your RAM gets cleared up from one end.

Comment: With 11 elements, you have `39916800` permutations that you have to multiply by size of a permutation...

Comment: You may reserve size of vector to avoid to have *random* size and lost space.

Comment: BTW, `routePattern` seems to be equals to `route`, and so you can directly do `routeFormation.push_back(route);`.

Comment: @Jarod42 oh technically i just wasted the ram for the FOR loop ? thanks for info.I will directly push_back the data then.

Comment: @PoojaNilangekar any tutorial or link for multithreading it ? I would like to learn about it

Comment: @JoachimPileborg by memory map the file, is the performance will get huge affect? i can compute 10 points within 1s + but if output as file it taking too long.

Comment: @Kenway Memory mapping is like read from or writing to any other hard-drive, the difference is that the file is mapped into your process address-space so you can use it like any other allocated memory. You simply have to measure and profile the code, to see if it's fast enough for your requirements, otherwise you have to limit the amount of data so it fits in memory.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks for the tips, I m going to read about memory map and try it out.

Comment: @Kenway [This tutorial](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/12/16/cpp-11-thread-tutorial/) is fairly simple to follow. Also in your case you might have to use mutex as std::vertex isn't thread safe.

Comment: @PoojaNilangekar Thanks a lot , I m reading the tutorial ,thanks for the help

Comment: Is there possible way to split the next permutation ? such as ,while (next_permutation(route.begin() + 1, route.begin()+3)) and then while (next_permutation(route.begin() + 3, route.end())) ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, its better to use dequeue for large portions of data because dequeue allocates data in chunks rather than in one large portion (vector guarantees that all data can be accessed like c array)

Archivation can be used to reduce required memory, archived data can be either stored in memory or to disk. There are a lot of archivation libraries for c/c++, for example

http://nih.at/libzip/

Comment: what is dequeue ? sorry I just saw this reply. i need to retain all the route pattern as later on i need to know which one is the shortest path

Comment: dequeue is double-ended queue: std::dequeue can be used in the same way as vector except for usage like c-array via pointer to some element http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/

Comment: If you push_back to vector without reserved size, reallocation is initiated. For example, when you add entry to vector that contains 1000 entries, memory for 1001 will be allocated, 1000 entries will be copied - only after that, memory for previous 1000 entries can be released. Splitting data in chunks solves this issue in dequeue